# rnx-kit: Do you have to run `npx rnx-dep-check --init library` for every library in your project individually?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, package.json, dependency-management

I'm going through the [guide](https://microsoft.github.io/rnx-kit/docs/guides/dependency-management) for `rnx-kit` and in the `Onboarding` section it says `generate the dependency manager configuration for your package` using `npx rnx-dep-check --init library`. In my React Native app, I have about 20 packages in my `package.json`. Do I run this command for each of them individually?

Answer (score 0):

No, you simply need to run this command once for the whole project.